# CMD: assigning IP to variable to get location

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I would like to get the *location* of my external IP address in Window's command prompt upon double-clicking a .cmd or .bat file.

To the best of my knowledge this requires at least two steps in CMD:

**Step 1: Getting my external IP:**

```
curl ip-adresim.app
```

Output:

> 216.58.194.46

**Step 2: Getting that IP's location:**

```
curl ipinfo.io/216.58.194.46
```

Output:

> {
> "ip": "216.58.194.46",
> "hostname": "dfw25s12-in-f46.1e100.net",
> "city": "San Francisco",
> "region": "California",
> "country": "US",
> "loc": "37.7749,-122.4194",
> "org": "AS15169 Google LLC",
> "postal": "94102",
> "timezone": "America/Los_Angeles",
> "readme": "https://ipinfo.io/missingauth"
> }

I would have to connect both steps by a common variable to make this an automated script, right.

But how?

Comment: Before you delete this again, try `for /f %%e in ('curl ip-adresim.app') do curl ipinfo.io/%%e&pause` (if you run this directly from the prompt, `%%e` becomes `%e` and you can drop the `&pause`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used ipinfo.io/city for this if you would like to capture this information in one step:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%curl.exe -s ipinfo.io/city') do set "_myLocation=%%g"
if defined _myLocation echo %_myLocation%
```

This was under the assumption you were just looking for the City. I'm not sure what you mean by "Input Text,"' but if you want the IP, City and Country, you could do the following:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%curl.exe -s ipinfo.io/ip') do set "_myIP=%%g"
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%curl.exe -s ipinfo.io/city') do set "_myCity=%%g"
for /f "tokens=*" %%g in ('%__APPDIR__%curl.exe -s ipinfo.io/country') do set "_myCountry=%%g"
if defined _myIP echo External IP: %_myIP%
if defined _myCity echo City: %_myCity%
if defined _myCountry echo Country: %_myCountry%
```

Comment: I'll accept this answer, although the output format isn't quite what I was hoping for. Maybe you can still help me get the 3 infos 1. curl.exe -s ipinfo.io/ip • 2. curl.exe -s ipinfo.io/city • 3. curl.exe -s ipinfo.io/country into 3 separate output lines without the input text (@echo off) to make IP, City and Country easily readable? Thanks!

Comment: @TantoMano I edited the code to display the IP, City and Country. Let me know if this is the format you need.